# Canvas по центру экрана, но торчит слева и сверху белый фон. Элементы тоже не по центру

Tags: html, css, canvas

[image: Прелоадер не по центру]

С canvas решил проблему просто залил фон тем же цветом, а вот прелоадер не от центровать никак он как и кнопка немного в право и в низ уходит.... Думаю это связанно с канвасом, но он по центру... че делать ... Ниже код канваса

````
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: #1b2838;
   z-index: 9999;
}
#preloader .spinner {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   border: 0.2em solid #df6242;
   border-top: 0.2em solid #1b2838;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 6em;
   height: 6em;
   animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
   0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
   100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}


 html, body {
   overflow: hidden;
   background: #1b2838;
 }

.canvas {
   background-color: #1b2838;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   
 }
 
 #canvas-container {
   position: absolute;
 }
 
 #myCanvas {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
@keyframes spin {
   0% { transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg); }
   100% { transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg); }
}
```